# Anything wrong with Object.freeze() on a JavaScript prototype?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

Is there anything wrong with calling `Object.freeze` on a constructor's prototype in JavaScript?

I was just thinking that since the prototype is shared amongst *all* instances, perhaps I can ensure that nobody overwrites anything in the prototype by freezing it, since overwriting something on the prototype affects every instance. So for instance, something like the following:

```
function MyConstructor() {
  // Stuff
}

MyConstructor.prototype = {
  method1() {
    // more stuff
  },
  method2() {
    // even more stuff
  },
  someArray: ['some', 'values'],
  someValue: 'value'
}

Object.freeze(MyConstructor.prototype);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you freeze the prototype you also freeze the the objects extending it, so they won't be able to override those properties defined in the prototype

This [gist](https://gist.github.com/felthy/5283131) is a test to showcase the problem

Comment: Yes, you cannot simply assign to those properties. But no, the inheriting objects are not frozen, and you still can create shadowing properties by using `Object.defineProperty`.

Comment: True, but the point is that freezing a prototype when it's instances are used elsewhere can cause all sort of problems. Unless you plan for it accordingly beforehand of course.

Comment: @Bergi How would you "freeze" the prototype without affecting objects that "extend" from it? I'd like object that "extend" from it to still easily shadow the prototype without `defineProperty`, but for modifying the prototype itself not to be allowed. Do we have to set the descriptors manually in this case (f.e. configurable/writable to false)?

Comment: @trusktr You might get away with doing this using getters/setters instead of setting `writable` to false.

Comment: @Bergi I'd like to make writing directly to a prototype not allowed, but writing to "extending" objects allowed (let them shadow the prototype). Is that only possible with Proxy, or is there another way? I don't know what properties users will define, so with getters/setters I'd have to keep a separate WeakMap to hold the values after converting their non-getter/setter props to getters/setters. Seems like it could be overly complicated.

Comment: @trusktr You only need the getters/setters for the properties of your prototype. Properties that don't exist can always be shadowed without problems.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. I was hoping to make protected and private member prototypes non-modifiable, to expose them on a `.super` property in https://github.com/trusktr/lowclass, but I think there might be a better way.

Comment: @trusktr If you want to make them non-modifiable, you should make them non-shadowable anyway imo.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you actually want is

```
MyConstructor.prototype.someArray = Object.freeze(['some', 'values']);
```

There's hardly a point for freezing the prototype object itself, nothing does overwrite prototype properties by accident. It might be useful to make inherited *values* *immutable* however, as accidental mutation happens much easier and causes the same detrimental effects.